# Google Sheets Vertical Plus Horizontal Vlookup with multiple column in criteria and result based on date

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I am trying to get the result in Column M based on user input in column J,K and L by searching data from Column A to H. An example for reference is given below:

[image]

Any help on above will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(J3:J10&K3:K10&L3:L10, QUERY(SORT(
 {A3:A10&B3:B10&C3:C10, D3:D10;
  A3:A10&B3:B10&E3:E10, F3:F10;
  A3:A10&B3:B10&G3:G10, H3:H10}), "where Col2 is not null", ), 2, 1)))
```

[image]

---

### update 1:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/IFNA(VLOOKUP(J3:J10&K3:K10&L3:L10, QUERY(SORT(
 {A3:A10&B3:B10&C3:C10, IFERROR(D3:D10/0, 0);
  A3:A10&B3:B10&E3:E10, IFERROR(F3:F10/0, 0);
  A3:A10&B3:B10&G3:G10, IFERROR(H3:H10/0, 0);
  A3:A10&B3:B10&C3:C10, D3:D10;
  A3:A10&B3:B10&E3:E10, F3:F10;
  A3:A10&B3:B10&G3:G10, H3:H10}), "where Col2 is not null", ), 2, 1)))))
```

[image]

---

### update 2:

```
=INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(J3:J10&K3:K10, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A3:A10&B3:B10)),
 IFERROR(1/(1/IFNA(VLOOKUP(J3:J10&K3:K10&L3:L10, QUERY(SORT(
 {A3:A10&B3:B10&C3:C10, IFERROR(D3:D10/0, 0);
  A3:A10&B3:B10&E3:E10, IFERROR(F3:F10/0, 0);
  A3:A10&B3:B10&G3:G10, IFERROR(H3:H10/0, 0);
  A3:A10&B3:B10&C3:C10, D3:D10;
  A3:A10&B3:B10&E3:E10, F3:F10;
  A3:A10&B3:B10&G3:G10, H3:H10}), "where Col2 is not null", ), 2, 1)))), ))
```

[image]

Comment: @ player0 Thanks for the great solution, it works perfect and fine, however, I found a case which need to be covered. If you select C2 and I1 and date as 30/09/22 then it will show the rate of C1 I3 i.e 375 (the result in this case should be blank as the rate of C2 I1 starts from 01/10/22). In other words if for the selected parameter there is no rate then result should be blank.

Comment: @Edyphant answer updated. try now

Comment: @ player0 Bravo... It works perfect and result is as expected ....what a creative approach you have applied..... hats off ....Thanks a lot for the excellent solution and special thanks for super quick reply.

Comment: @player0 User Input Customer 1 | Item 1 | 15/1/22 and Customer 2 | Item 4 | 31/12/22  Doesn't exist in the data right?, i think the desired output is incorrect in the question, is it? [See this](https://i.imgur.com/g4Mt6Gj.png) green exist, red doesn't.

Comment: @Osm as I understood it we either want to return the exact match or closest (past) match chance the use of 1 instead of 0 as the 4th vlookup parameter

Comment: aha, Make a note in the answer or edit the op question.

Comment: @ player0, after practically implication your wonderful solution for few days came across a situation which is giving incorrect results. if I select C1 and I4 then no rate should be reflected (as there is not rate for this combination) however it is taking the nearest match of C1 I3. Can you share your expert solution to this.

Comment: @Edyphant can you share a copy of your sheet with the scenario that fails?

Comment: @player0 Thanks for your response. Here is the link, result in cell M9 is not corect. It should be blank but it shows the nearest match from H5. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bUf40ka3uA2kg2tlnbvvtUR_KQu3fgP3RXLKM5As36c/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @Edyphant try: `=INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(J3:J10&K3:K10, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A3:A10&B3:B10)),
 IFERROR(1/(1/IFNA(VLOOKUP(J3:J10&K3:K10&L3:L10, QUERY(SORT(
 {A3:A10&B3:B10&C3:C10, IFERROR(D3:D10/0, 0);
  A3:A10&B3:B10&E3:E10, IFERROR(F3:F10/0, 0);
  A3:A10&B3:B10&G3:G10, IFERROR(H3:H10/0, 0);
  A3:A10&B3:B10&C3:C10, D3:D10;
  A3:A10&B3:B10&E3:E10, F3:F10;
  A3:A10&B3:B10&G3:G10, H3:H10}), "where Col2 is not null", ), 2, 1)))), ))`

Comment: @player0.... Thanks for your response... as usual your solution worked perfect...

Comment: @player0, your solution is working perfect, however, I faced an issue & for reference am sharing the sheet link:- If data is entered in A10 without value in B and C then in column M result will be fetched for data for which no rate is available. In the sheet data should not be fetched in M3, M5 and M9 but still data is being fetched. This is not creating issue as if we remove data from A10 the result will be correct & perfect so nothing to worry. Am just sharing issue for knowledge purpose.   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bUf40ka3uA2kg2tlnbvvtUR_KQu3fgP3RXLKM5As36c/edit#gid=309749190